# How to integrate a dropright menu within a dropdown menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

In the navbar I have a dropdown menu called "Indicator" which has the following items: indicator 1, indicator 2, indicator 3. Under "Indicator 1", there are a couple of options that I want to display as a dropright menu.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Indicators
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-dropright" href="#">Indicator 1
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 2</a>
                </div>
              </a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Indicator 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Indicator 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
```

I am unable to make it work. Can you please share a code snippet that shows an example of how it is done ?

Answer (score 0):

[Check Live demo here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h)

```
<style>
    .dropdown-submenu {
      position: relative;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
      top: 0;
      left: 100%;
      margin-top: -1px;
    }
    </style>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Multi-Level Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>In this example, we have created a .dropdown-submenu class for multi-level dropdowns (see style section above).</p>
  <p>Note that we have added jQuery to open the multi-level dropdown on click (see script section below).</p>                                        
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>
```